# Send value through double qoute/single qoute?

Tags: linux, bash, lua, ash

So i have a ash script that send command to device via telnet
The command look like this.

```
echo 'dofile("lcdprint.lua").lcdprint("date")' | telnet 192.168.1.23 23
```

I want the output date like this

```
Tue Jul 12 17:10:51 WIB 2016
```

But instead of above output, the code run unexpected with this result

```
date
```

How do i send the correct command? The output should contain date value, not 'date' string.
Thankyou :)

Comment: Thank you mklement0, it's working!
Indeed, i'm using nodemcu firmware with lua language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to incorporate the output from *locally* executing the `date` utility, before sending the command string to the target machine, use `$(...)`, Bash's [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution):

```
echo "dofile('lcdprint.lua').lcdprint('$(date)')" | telnet 192.168.1.23 23
```

<sup>Note how the overall string is *double-quoted* to ensure that `$(...)` is expanded.</sup>

If you want to run `date` *on the target machine*, use Lua's `os.execute()` to run a shell command:

```
echo 'dofile("lcdprint.lua").lcdprint(os.execute("date"))' | telnet 192.168.1.23 23
```

<sup>Note how the overall string is *single-quoted*, because no interpretation by Bash is needed in this case, and using single quotes ensures that the string is passed as-is.</sup>